# How to send an html email in lotus notes 8.5

Tags: html, mule, lotus-notes

I have read about the problems with Lotus notes not rendering styles and some other things properly, but my problem hasn't gotten that far. My end goal is to send an email through the mule ESB and have the email render as html. In trying to get this to work, I simply want to send a simple markup in the body and have it render. Once i can figure this out, I can try to build on it to get everything else correct.

My simple email message I would like to send is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestingStuff</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

And I would like to receive the email which just says Hello! When I receive the email, it is exactly as typed, it does not get rendered as html. Do I need to do anything else to specify that this should be rendered as HTML opposed to plain text?

Comment: You are probably sending as plain text and not MIME.

Comment: Thanks, How can I change this? Can I add something in the body of the email?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you use to generate and send the email.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am not quite ready to send the email through code. I just want to understand how to accomplish rendering html in a very simple fashion. I am using no code yet, just opening Notes, clicking new and sending an email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just enter HTML into the Notes client and expect it to work. And even if you tell Lotus Notes that you're entering HTML, you can't expect the message it creates to be exactly like one that you're going to create in code. You can't really even expect it to be close.

If you want to send a test email message into a Notes user and retain complete control over the contents of the message, so that it will be processed exactly the way a message that you would from code will be, then I suggest that you learn [how to use telnet to send a message to an SMTP server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx), and learn about the [structure of MIME messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) from [a good general tutorial](http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/mime.html), or from [a tutorial that deals specifically with email messages with text/html content](http://abiglime.com/webmaster/articles/cgi/010698.htm).

Comment: The first line is exactly what I was looking for (but not hoping for!) Followed with some documentation on achieving the desired results. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Notes 9 you can use "File" -> "Import" and then select your HTML file.
I don't know if that's possible in Notes 8.5 too.